# convert date as string int64 format

Tags: java, json, string, timestamp

I need to call one API which having payload

```
JSON
{
timeAsString  :String
}
```

it is given in the document

```
timeAsString  (int64 (https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/type-format) format) Timestamp when abc is happen
```

For that i converted date into milliseconds and send as a string

```
new Date().getTime().toString();
```

but it gives me error as invalid argument
please let us know where i am wrong. how can we send date in string int64 format?

Comment: Post the code snippet which is throwing the exception.

Comment: I want to know my way to send  timeAsString value is correct or not .Or there is some another way to send date value in int64 format as string?

Comment: Describe the format and show example data.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

First, please consider using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. The `Date` class that you are using is long outdated and poorly designed. The modern API is much nicer to work with.

```
    String timeAsString = String.valueOf(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
```

This just gave:

```
1512197790622
```

Another option is `String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())`.

### Q&A

**How do I learn to use `java.time`?** You can start out from [the **Oracle tutorial**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and/or find other tutorials and other resources on the net.

**Can I use the modern API with my Java version?**

If using at least Java **6**, you can.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)).
- On Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP, and I think that there’s a wonderful explanation in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**What was wrong with my code?** `Date.getTime()` returns the milliseconds as a primitive `long`. In Java you cannot call any methods on a primitive. In my Eclipse I got the error message ”Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type long“. One solution is to use `String.valueOf()` as I did in my code above.